# Firebird embedded in .net

Tags: .net, firebird

I'm trying to reproduce situation as is at this [page](http://nazmialtun.blogspot.com/2012/01/using-embedded-firebird-database-in-net.html).
Db tables with generators and triggers are generated but I'm struggle with adding reference to the project inside visual studio.

`FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` is succ. added but when I'm try to add any of this files

```
fbembed.dll ·         icudt30.dll ·         icuin30.dll ·            icuuc30.dll
```

I'm getting error on adding reference like this
**A reference to d:....fbembded.dll could not be added.  Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that is a valid assembly or COM component.**

I tried with moving this files to another disk location but same thing happens.

Comment: AFAIK (but not 100% sure) you shouldn't add references to the files needed for Firebird embedded: they are not C# assemblies or COM components. Just include them (as files) in your project. Also note that the page you link to only says to add a reference to `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient`, not to the other files (the screenshot confirms this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you link to already answers your question. You should not add the embedded Firebird files as references, just as plain files (and make sure to enable copy to output directory):

> After we download it, we add 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient .dll' as reference in our project.  For  embedded usage of firebird database we also need to download some dll files and add our project.
>   Go ,  http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/server-packages/    and download  embedded package.
>   Add
>
> - fbembed.dll
> - icudt30.dll
> - icuin30.dll
> - icuuc30.dll
>
> in your project  as  file  and   set   Copy To Output Directory  property  as  Copy always So those dll files will  always be  copied to output directory.
>
> [image]

Comment: @panjo Don't be sad, at first read it looks like it says to add references for those files as well